# DDL sync informatica

Tags: oracle, ddl

I have a question: I have a table (say `tableA`) in a database (say `dbA`) and I need to mirror `tableA` as another table (say `tableB`) in another database (say `dbB`).

I know this can be done via (materialised) view or via informatica. But by problem is that I need to sync DDL as well. For example if a column is added in `tableA`, the column should automatically reflect in `tableB`.

Can this be done anyway directly via oracle or Informatica.

(or I will have to write a procedure to sync table on basis of all_tab_cols).

Comment: As far as I know DDL could be synced only if second DB run as replica (by active data guard)

Comment: even I thought that :(

Comment: perhaps i would have to write a custom code to acheive this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could:

1. [create another database as a logical standby database with Data Guard](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41134/create_ls.htm#SBYDB00300)
2. [use Oracle Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17069/toc.htm)

I would use (2) if you just need a single table in the other database or (1) if you need an entire schema (or more).